# Error: `experimental.runtime` requires `experimental.reactRoot` to be enabled along with React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I've a project with (next 12.1.6 + react 18.1 + react-dom 18.1). Now i want to add React Server Components to it. Updated my **next.config.js** like this

```
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: '../../.next',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    runtime: 'nodejs',
    serverComponents: true,
    concurrentFeatures: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

But regardless of that, when i execute **npm run start:dev** (**npm run build** works fine i believe) i get the error:

`` Error: `experimental.runtime` requires `experimental.reactRoot` to be enabled along with React 18. at Object.getBaseWebpackConfig [as default] (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\next\build\webpack-config.ts:355:11) at async Promise.all (index 0) at Span.traceAsyncFn (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\next\trace\trace.ts:106:14) at Span.traceAsyncFn (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\next\trace\trace.ts:106:14) at HotReloader.start (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\next\server\dev\hot-reloader.ts:518:21) at DevServer.prepare (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\next\server\dev\next-dev-server.ts:404:5) at ViewService.onModuleInit (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\src\server\view\view.service.ts:19:7) at async Promise.all (index 0) at Object.callModuleInitHook (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\@nestjs\core\hooks\on-module-init.hook.js:43:5) at NestApplication.callInitHook (G:\ORLVNIcard\orlvni-business-card\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-application-context.js:169:13) ``

Next.js documentation says in https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components that i should use **next@canary** instead of **next@12.1.6**, and it works, but i have another problem with **@canary** in [HookWebpackError: The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552260/hookwebpackerror-the-to-argument-must-be-of-type-string-received-undefined) and **@12.1.6** does **not** throw the error in fresh barely empty project with (next 12.1.6 + react 18.1 + react-dom 18.1).

Part of my **package.json** looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build && cd src/client && next build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.10",
    "mssql": "^7.3.0",
    "next": "^12.1.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.45.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
```

And this is how i start my next app

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import createServer from 'next';
import { NextServer } from 'next/dist/server/next';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class ViewService implements OnModuleInit {
  private server: NextServer;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.server = createServer({
        dev: this.configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV') !== 'production',
        dir: './src/client',
      });
      await this.server.prepare();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  handler(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return this.server.getRequestHandler()(req, res);
  }
}
```

Guess the error is due to next somehow not seeing react 18 in **@12.1.6**, but i can't realize why, especially while in new project everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding `reactRoot: true` to the `experimental` object in `next.config.js`?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, as i remember i was getting "you need to have react 18 to use experimental reactRoot" error or something like this. btw i've found the solution already, thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error was thrown 'cause by default **createServer()** method of Next.js is creating react server with react 17 and old methods of react, like **render()**, **hydrate()** and so on. To make **createServer()** create react 18 server it's necessary to define `__NEXT_REACT_ROOT` as `true` in the environment of the process of our custom server. At least i've understood it this way. So the solution is

```
async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    process.env.__NEXT_REACT_ROOT = 'true';
    try {
      this.server = createServer({
        dev: this.configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV') !== 'production',
        dir: './src/client',
      });
      await this.server.prepare();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your package-lock.json and install the canary version of next

```
npm install next@canary react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Then add expermiental settings in your next.config.js

```
 experimental: { 
      reactRoot: true, 
      runtime: "nodejs", 
      serverComponents: true, 
      concurrentFeatures: true 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your .env file and it will fix the issue

```
__NEXT_REACT_ROOT=true
```